# Text goes outside containing div

Tags: css, css-position

I have this [codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgbLB), shouldn't the text goes to new line when it reaches the right border of div?

**html:**

```
<div class="test">

    <p>dfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodjdfsjiodj</p>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
div.test{
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    margin:1px; padding:1px;

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `word-wrap:break-word`

```
div.test{
    width:400px;
    height:800px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    margin:1px; padding:1px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: breaks words apart, I don't like.

Answer (score 2):

Live Example
http://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/LAhJw

```
div.test {word-break:break-all;}
```

Comment: In my case width percentage was not working because container was scrollable. So I had to add                                                                                                                                  
{
  word-break:break-all;
  max-width: 65%;
}

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, word break didn't look too pretty for me - so I found applying the below CSS to the container worked:

```
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 overflow: hidden;
```

ellipsis has good browser support too, [read more about ellipsis here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Answer (score 0):

in my case it turned out to be this:

```
something&nbsp;something
```

counts as a single long word and hence went outside the div

Fixed it by doing

```
something&nbsp; something
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the text doesn't have any space, so it won't create a new line.

Try to put:

`[space]/(&nbsp;)/(&#160;)`

For example, I changed my text from:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

into:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It will create its own new line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do  `width:auto;`, but if you want specific `width:400px;` you can use `word-wrap:break-word` or `word-wrap:break-all;`

Comment: I would suggest `width: fit-content;`